# jqplot pie chart with empty dataset

Tags: dataset, jqplot, pie-chart

I want to have an empty pie chart in case when no data has been given to draw a pie chart.

If I am passing an empty array for dataset then it is not rendering anything in canvas.

Can anybody update me how I can manage this, when there is not any data it should draw a blank circle so that user can feel like chart is there but not having any data to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. I used 2 functions to differently draw for no data & data present. In no-data, I used 1 as input to show full circle but with colors and tags that convey no data present.